# How to make Modal Service in IONIC?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

I am sorry. I am starter on IONIC, i am going to use a modal service in a app. so i can only change the template url...? the modal is shown, but i can't close the modal by the closeModal() function.
Here is my factory.

```
.factory('ModalSvc',function($ionicModal, $rootScope){
    return {
        setModalView : function( url ) {
            $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(url, {
                scope: $rootScope
            }).then(function(modal) {
                $rootScope.modal = modal;
            });
        },
        openModal : function() {
            $rootScope.modal.show();
        },
        closeModal : function() {
            $rootScope.modal.hide();
        }
    }
});
```

In a controller:

```
ModalSvc.setModalView('templates/popup-search-order.html');
    $rootScope.openModel = function () {
        ModalSvc.openModal();
    };
    $rootScope.hideModel = function () {
        ModalSvc.closeModal();
    };
```

What's wrong? and what i have to for close the modal view...
This is possible problem. That is, i can use a modal dialog service instead of some modal view...?
Thank you in advance.
Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this a lot with apps I am working on now. There are a few general angular concepts you will need to understand in depth; 1 is Promises using $q and the other is all the gotchas around scopes and using $rootScope. I will let you do that research on your own or learn as you get your fingers burned now and again while using it (muhahahahaha) See code below.

```
.factory('ModalSvc',function($ionicModal, $rootScope, $q){
return {
    setModalView : setModalView
}
function setModalView(url) {
        var def = $q.defer();
        var modalScope = $rootScope.$new();
        modalScope.cancelModal = cancelModal;

        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(url, {
            scope: modalScope
        }).then(function(modal) {
            modalScope.modal = modal;
            modalScope.modal.show();
        });

        function cancelModal() {
            modalScope.modal.hide();
            modalScope.modal.remove();
            // you can resolve the result of the modal here
            def.resolve();
        }
        return def.promise;
    }
});
```

You html could then look like this

```
<ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <button class="button button-clear button-icon icon ion-close-round" ng-click="cancelModal()"></button>
        <h1 class="title">Modal Title</h1>

    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content has-header="true">

    </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: How can i open the modal?

Comment: Edited the code, I added modal.show() in the then callback